# Ajax выводит только первое слово

Tags: python, html, ajax

Народ, помогите пожалуйста, я не силен в ajax, почему мой код передает на сервер только первое слово до пробела(например "по позиции" выведется только "по") ? нужно передать полное строковое выражение под переменной veget, которая передается из html data-veget

```
$(document).ready (function () {

  $(".save").click( function() {
    $. ajax ({
      url: '/save/',
      type: "POST",
      datatype: 'json',
      data: ({name: $(this).closest('td').find('input[name="mas_vigr"]').val(),
              id:$(this).data('id'),
              veget:$(this).data('veget'),
              date:$(this).data('date')
      }),
      success: function () {
          consol.log('Ok', veget);
        }

    });
  });
});




  <form action="/save/" method="POST" name="save" id = 'form' onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13">
    <input data-class={{row[5]}} id='mas_vigr'  type="number" name="mas_vigr" />

    <input class='save' data-id={{row[5]}} data-veget={{row[2]}} data-date={{row[0]}} type="button" value="Записать">
    </form>
```

Comment: Потому что значение html-атрибута вы не завернули в кавычки, а значит значение атрибута заканчивается на первом пробеле, то есть как раз после первого слова

Comment: т.е надо было так:   data-veget="{{row[2]}}"   ?

Comment: @andreymal  Спасибо тебе большое. помогло. Как отметить твой ответ полезным?